# GreenDao comparing Dates in where condition

Tags: android, database, sqlite, greendao

I have a problem while using greendao. It is working great so far. But I think there is a problem when I tried out comparing the dates. Following is the case

I have a table lets call it **OrderTable**. I have two dates as column, **OrderDate** and **DeliveryDate**. Now I want to select those records whose **DeliveryDate** is Null or whose **OrderDate** is greater then **DeliveryDate**

I want to make this in Where clause to select record. But it is giving me following error

> org.greenrobot.greendao.DaoException: Illegal date value: expected java.util.Date or Long for value org.greenrobot.greendao.Property@41d032a0

So I am helpless in comparing 2 dates even the Is Null is not working even though I know the dates are null in some record.

Please help me. I am stuck in it.

Answer (score 0):

For checking if Date object is null or not we need to use this:

```
 daoSession.getModelDao().queryBuilder().where(ModelDao.Properties.SyncedAt.isNull()).list();
```

and

```
daoSession.getModelDao().queryBuilder().where(ModelDao.Properties.SyncedAt.isNotNull()).list();
```

To compare dates we need to use this:

```
gt() and lt()
```

example

```
        List<Model> items = daoSession.getModelDao().queryBuilder()
        .where(ModelDao.Properties.StartTime.gt(fourAMTomorrow),
        ModelDao.Properties.EndTime.lt(endAt), ModelDao.Properties.Date.eq(date))
        .list();
```

Hope this will help someone.